# Is it possible to archive civi events?

Tags: civievent

Does anyone know of a way to archive old civi events? We're starting to build up quite a number and being able to archive some so that the current or at least relatively recent events were all that showed in our events list would be great.

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: may be you can explain where you see them in your 'event list' eg the url that shows them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to "separate" past events by **creating a new/additional category for them,** named i.e. "archived". 
In backend events management, you only see present and upcoming events (default). In frontend-calendars, you can exclude past events from being displayed or exclude categories ("archived"). In the frontend list-views, only present and upcoming events are displaying. 
Further advantage of a using a category: you can create a [CiviRule](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) to automatically assign/unassign the respective categories once the event is x days/hours/months in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find that all events archive themselves, provided that you have either entered an end date in each instance, or that each has been marked as disabled.  You can find the controls in /civicrm/events/manage events.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It was just that the people using the system in the backend have set up quite a lot of future events and they're struggling to quickly find a particular one when they need to. It turns out that they no longer really wanted to see those events that were fully 'sold out' in the 'Manage Events' list even though they were upcoming because they didn't need to be actively managed. I guess we could change their status to 'inactive' and that might help separate them out but perhaps that might have unforeseen consequences...