# Log and Event Management

Tags: logs, civicrm-event

Our live CIVICRM environment is CiviCRM 5.67.1, Joomla 4.4.2, PHP 8.1, hosted on Siteground.

The logs in our environment are very large and growing.  Is there a process that we can use to manage the size of the system and job log?  Other than not having access to the history, is there any harm in deleting the records in the log files?

Additionally, is there an archiving process for past events?

Looking for reasons why the system is so slow.

Answer (score 1):

In what the archiving for past events is concerned, please find my answer under: [Is it possible to archive civi events?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/46123/is-it-possible-to-archive-civi-events/46126#46126)

The logs can be deleted if you don't need them anymore.

Eileen wrote a good article about that: https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/who-did-what-when

What's the URL of your site?
Do you run CiviMobile API on this installation?

*** EDIT ***
Deactivate CiviMobile API under extensions when editing/adding events. Then, the overall performance will be fine. There is a performance issue with CiviMobile API: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/issues/73

Or you could use the fix described here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/merge_requests/78/diffs

Comment: URL is https://www.enosuccess.com    We do run CIVIMOBILE

Comment: Deactivate CiviMobile API under extensions when editing/adding events. Then, the overall performance will be fine. There is a performance issue with CiviMobile API: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/issues/73

Comment: Or you could use the fix described here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/merge_requests/78/diffs

Comment: I quickly inspected your website and found that URL-creation/configuration is far from good. Please change your htaccess.txt to .htaccess and turn on Joomla SEF URL's. The attempt to open  https://www.enosuccess.com/index.php/directory/member-directory results in an error 500.